# What is the meaning of the last part of this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

这也是人之常情。毕竟嘛，世人都知道，王爷从小就想娶冷王妃，好不容易抱得美人归，那个时候一定是喜不自胜，金风玉露一相逢便胜却人间无数.

> I don't understand "金风玉露一相逢便胜却人间无数."

Comment: From Help Center (http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): 

We are happy to assist with your translation questions if you are having a specific problem. *Please show your attempt at translation in your question and state which area you are having difficulty with.*

Open ended questions regarding the accuracy of a translation or *asking for a translation of a word or passage without showing previous effort are not allowed.*

Comment: iciba：金风玉露， 。。。泛指秋天的景物    http://wenda.tianya.cn/question/21e1cda095f9e88c
。。。意思是若两个相爱的人若能相逢,虽时日短暂,也是难能可贵.,就仅此一次相逢,已抵过了世间无数的美好幸福
（meeting in autumn scenery only this one time achieves countless perfect happiness？）

Answer (score 1):

金风玉露一相逢便胜却人间无数 is a quote from the poem 《鹊桥仙·纤云弄巧》 by Song dynasty poet 秦观.

It is actually two lines:

```
金风玉露一相逢
便胜却人间无数
```

Let's parse them separately:

> 金风玉露一相逢

This has three parts:

1. 金风 = golden wind
2. 玉露 = jade dew
3. 一相逢 = upon meeting once

This line means something like: upon encountering (each other) in the golden wind and jade dew.

> 便胜却人间无数

1. 便 = With that
2. 胜却 = be greater than
3. 人间 = humanity
4. 无数 = innumerable

So this line means something like: with that (their experience) surpassed the experience of countless people.

So together the line means (translated more loosely): Upon meeting each other under the golden evening wind and amongst the pure white dew, they shared an experience that others would never understand.